# Have there been any attempts to get the tag algorithm from Facebook's Kaggle competition?

Tags: discussion, tags, facebook, suggested-tags

Facebook held [a competition on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/facebook-recruiting-iii-keyword-extraction) for data scientists to bag a job with them.

The challenge was to use the Stack Exchange data dump and find a way to predict the tags given the title and body of a new question.

I don't find any way of getting the codes for each entry on Kaggle itself, but Facebook probably has access to them.

Have there been any attempts to get the algorithms and implement one of them?

Comment: Worth noting, the crafty guy that _wrote_ our tag predictor also entered the contest just to see how our actual implementation would stack up to the submissions. I don't have any additional word on how that went.

Comment: just ran across this nice writeup of some of the results: [Keyword Extraction and Semantic Tag Prediction](http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2013/FangHong-Keyword%20Extraction%20and%20Semantic%20Tag%20Prediction.pdf) Hong/Fang